# solution of switched ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\dot x= A_{\sigma}x+B_{\sigma}u$ where $\sigma:\mathbb{R}\to\{1,2,\dots,p\}\subsetneq\mathbb{N}$ is the switching signal, $A_i$ is $n\times n$, $B_i$ is
$n\times m$ matrix, $p$ is the number of different subsystems, $x(t):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a state variable, $u:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is the input. In other words, the system is modeled as a time varying linear differential equation whose co-efficient matrices are piecewise constant. The time variance follows from the action of the switches present in the system.

In general switches or component faults induce jumps in certain state variables, in order to allow jumps in the solution we can make our solution space in  distributional solution framework. So, in general solutions may consists of Dirac impulses and/or their derivatives?

Now my question is how to get a globally defined solution for the switched ODE for a given $\sigma$?

Comment: Actually, a antiderivative of a jump is the absolute value. So I expect sharp corners more than Dirac impulses in the solution.

Comment: Could you please explain your first line mathematically? I am really not expert in this topi, so bit details will help me to understand better.

Comment: That's nothing deep, actually. I just said that $$\frac{d}{dx}|x|=\begin{cases} 1, & x>0 \\ -1, & x<0, \end{cases} $$ so "a sharp corner" (i.e. a modification of the absolute value) gives a jump upon differentiation. It should be noted that the last equation is undefined at $x=0$. However, if you interpret $|x|$ and the right-hand side as distribution, then the equation turns out to be true in distributional sense.